# How to create a dataframe on two conditions in a lambda function using apply after groupby()?

Tags: python, lambda, pandas-groupby, apply, quantile

I am trying to create portfolios in dataframes depended on the variable 'scope' leaving the rows with the highest 33% of the scope-values in the first portfolio in a dataframe, middle 34% in the second and bottom 33% in the third for each time period and industry.

So far, I grouped the data on date and industry

```
group_first = data_clean.groupby(['date','industry'])
```

and used a lambda function afterwards to get the rows of the first tercile of 'scope' for every date and industry; for instance:

```
port = group_first.apply(lambda x: x[x['scope'] <= x.scope.quantile(0.33)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This works for the first and third tercile, however not for the middle one, because I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

putting two condition in the lambda function, like this:

```
group_middle = data_clean.groupby(['date','industry'])
port_middle = group_middle.apply(lambda x: (x[x['scope'] > x.scope.quantile(0.67)]) and (x[x['scope'] < x.scope.quantile(0.33)])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

In other words, how can I get the rows of a dataframe containing the values in 'scope' between the 33rd and 67th percentile after grouping for date and industry?

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: maybe create normal function `def my_function(x): ...` and later use it in `apply(my_function)`. Inside `def my_function` you will ahve more space to add `print()` to see values in variables to see if it works correctly.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I'm not sure but pandas in some situations may need `&` instead of `and` and `|` instead of `or`

Comment: @furas thanks for your reply, I already tried to use & and unfortunately, it did not work. For the function you mentioned first, I would not know how to implement it...

Comment: don't you know how to create normal function ? Put code from `lambda` and use `return`. In normal function you can use `if/else` and code is more readable and easier to write something more complex. But more important you can use `print()` to display values in variables (and results from calculations) - so you can see if it works correctly. It can be easier then learning how to use debugger.

Comment: BTW: maybe you should use `x[ A & B ]`instead of `x[A] and x[B]` something like `x[ x['scope'] > x.scope.quantile(0.67) & x['scope'] < x.scope.quantile(0.33) ]`

Comment: I think you may have wrong `<` and `>` and you don't try to get `33...67` but `0...33 and 67...100` which is always empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will guess - I don't have data to test it.

You use wrong `<` and `>` and you check `scope<33 and scope>67` which gets `0...33 and 67...100` (and it may give empty data) but you need `scope>33 and scope<67` to get `33..67`

You may also use `x[ scope>33 & scope<67 ]` instead of `x[scope>33] and x[scope<67]`

```
port_middle = group_middle.apply(lambda x: 
   x[ 
      (x['scope'] > x.scope.quantile(0.33)) & (x['scope'] < x.scope.quantile(0.67)
   ]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```